# how to do array merge in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello Everyone i am new to PHP. I am doing the server side validation in php. I am facing problems while merging the arrays. Here is my code

I have 3 functions

```
$pfmt_input_group               = $pfmt_job["pfmt_input_group"];
$pfmt_input_group               = (array)$pfmt_input_group;
$group_array    = $this->validate_pfmt_input_group($pfmt_input_group,$validate_array);
```

this function internally calls pfmt_input_group_function
public function validate_pfmt_input_group($pfmt_input_group,$validate_array)
    {
        $pfmt_input_group_array = array();

```
    if(!empty($pfmt_input_group))
    {
        $inputs = $pfmt_input_group['inputs'];

        $job_validate_num_input = $this->validate_number($pfmt_input_group["num_input"],explode(",",$validate_array[15]));

        if($job_validate_num_input == "invalid")
        {
            array_push($pfmt_input_group_array, "Num_input value must be an integer");
        }

        $pfmt_input_validator_array = array();

        $num_input = $pfmt_input_group["num_input"];
        for ($input=0; $input < $num_input; $input++)
        {
            $pfmt_inputs            = $pfmt_input_group["inputs"][$input];
            $pfmt_inputs            = (array) $pfmt_inputs; 
            $pfmt_input             = $pfmt_inputs["pfmt_input"];
            $pfmt_input             = (array) $pfmt_input;  

            $pfmt_input_validator_array  = $this->validate_pfmt_input($pfmt_input,$validate_array);
        }
        $pfmt_input_group_array_result = array_merge((array)$pfmt_input_group_array,(array)$pfmt_input_validator_array);
    }
    return $pfmt_input_group_array_result;
}
```

This internally calls another function

```
public function validate_pfmt_input($pfmt_input,$validate_array)
{           
    $pfmt_input_array = array();

    if(!empty($pfmt_input))
    {
        $job_validate_num_track = $this->validate_number($pfmt_input["num_track"],explode(",",$validate_array[18]));

        if($job_validate_num_track == "invalid")
        {
            array_push($pfmt_input_array, "Num_track value must be an integer");
        }

        $job_validate_track_name = $this->validate_empty($pfmt_input["track_name"],explode(",",$validate_array[62]));

        if($job_validate_track_name == "blank")
        {
            array_push($pfmt_input_array, "Track_Name should not be empty");
        }

        $job_validate_num_stream = $this->validate_number($pfmt_input["num_stream"],explode(",",$validate_array[326]));

        if($job_validate_num_stream == "invalid")
        {
            array_push($pfmt_input_array, "Num_stream value must be an integer");
        }

        $pfmt_input_stream_validator_array = array();

        $streamer = $pfmt_input["num_stream"];              
        for ($stream=0; $stream < $streamer ; $stream++)
        {
            $pfmt_stream                 = $pfmt_input["streamer"][$stream];
            $pfmt_stream                 = (array) $pfmt_stream;
            $pfmt_input_stream           = $pfmt_stream["pfmt_input_stream"];
            $pfmt_input_stream           = (array) $pfmt_input_stream;
            $pfmt_input_stream_validator_array = $this->validate_pfmt_input_stream($pfmt_input_stream,$validate_array);
        }
        $pfmt_input_array_result = array_merge((array)$pfmt_input_array,(array)$pfmt_input_stream_validator_array);     
    }
    return $pfmt_input_array_result;
}
```

This is how it follows so i need an single array it containes all the internal error msgs i tried to merge all the arrays but i am not able to get the result
please help me to find this

Answer (score 0):

```
$pfmt_input_array_result = array_merge_recursive($pfmt_input_array,$pfmt_input_stream_validator_array);
```

Use this.